# Why Bing Map not showing

Tags: winrt-xaml

I have added all the required references like Bing Map and Others. I have added the credential as well.

The problem : There is no map showing

What need to be done?

```
<bm:Map Credentials="Am5qxl1jqY2FumxPaUtRWPUasxxxxxxxxxxxx " x:Name="myMap" 
                 MapType="Aerial" ZoomLevel="12"
                 Width="600" Margin="383,0,383,-593">
                <bm:Map.Center>                    
                   < bm:Location Latitude="40.72367" Longitude="40.72367" />
                </bm:Map.Center>

</bm:Map>
```

Comment: Have you set "active solution configuration" other than AnyCPU ? Is you Bing map key correct ? Have you added reference of Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime ?

Comment: In Configuration Manager, I set Bebug in Active Solution config, set x64 for Active Solution Platform. in Project Contexts it shows Config : Debug, Platform x86. Have added MS VC++ runtime and BingMap . Is this correct?

Comment: All things are correct. Is your Bing map key correct ?

Comment: Map key is correct. Finally, I have to change My Laptop's Location to USA to make it works. Is this means I have to change to USA location in order to test the Bing Map?

Comment: Are you getting image like [this](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC621159.png) ?

Comment: Yes, but WITHOUT the No-entry Sign.

Comment: Try to set `HomeRegion="US"` in `<bm:Map />`. Also change your region from control panel to original one (other than US).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `HomeRegion="US"` in `<bm:Map />`

[Here is the list of supported regions in Bing Map.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj670541.aspx)